# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Need help here. I have 2 questions based on this query.

```
SELECT cdd.FieldID,cdd.PlanTypeID,pt.IsFinancial            
FROM ClientDataDictionary cdd
    INNER JOIN #tblPlanTypes pt ON cdd.PlanTypeID = pt.PlanTypeID
    INNER JOIN ClientDataDictionaryFieldType cddftype
    ON cdd.FieldId = cddftype.FieldID AND cdd.PlanTypeId = cddftype.PlanTypeID
    WHERE cdd.ClientId = @ClientID AND cdd.IsHidden = 0
    AND cddftype.FieldTypeID = 4 
    AND cddftype.FieldID = cddftype.ParentFieldIDSectionTitle 
    AND  (SELECT COUNT(cddftype2.FieldID)
              FROM ClientDataDictionaryFieldType  cddftype2
              Where cddftype2.ParentFieldIDSectionTitle = cdd.FieldID
              AND cddftype2.PlanTypeID = cdd.PlanTypeID
              AND EXISTS(Select tbl.FieldID From #tblSelectedFields tbl
                          Where tbl.FieldID = cddftype2.FieldID AND tbl.PlantypeID =cdd.PlanTypeID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
              ) != 0 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

1. Where do I place my `COLLATE` keyword in this query? I know that temp tables have different collate "type".
2. I tried using `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` however, the error still occurs. Will this resolve the issue?

Please help me here. Thanks!

[UPDATE 1]
`ClientID` is set to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` data type.

[UPDATE 2]
here are the table definitions

`#tblPlanTypes`

```
PlanTypeId nvarchar(50),  
PlanType nvarchar(max),  
Prefix NVARCHAR(10),  
IsFinancial BIT,  
TotalCount BIGINT,  
PlanCount BIGINT
```

`ClientDataDictonary`

```
[ClientDataDictionaryId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL CONSTRAINT      [DF_ClientDataDictionary_ClientDataDictionaryId] DEFAULT (newid()),
[ClientId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[PlanTypeId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[FieldId] [nvarchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[FieldText] [nvarchar] (max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[FieldType] [nvarchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[DefaultValue] [nvarchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[HelpText] [nvarchar] (512) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[IsHidden] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ClientDataDictionary_IsHidden] DEFAULT ((0)),
[IsSummable] [bit] NULL,
[IsRequired] [bit] NULL,
[IsContractRenewal] [bit] NULL,
[HasAlert] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ClientDataDictionary_HasAlert] DEFAULT ((0)),
[AlertMessage] [nvarchar] (512) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[CentralLanguageId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[LookupTypeName] [varchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[RowVersion] [timestamp] NULL,
[LastUpdated] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ClientDataDictionary_LastUpdated] DEFAULT (getutcdate()),
[Sequence] [int] NULL
```

`ClientDataDictionaryFieldType`

```
[ClientDataDictionaryFieldTypeID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ClientDataDictionaryFieldType_ClientDataDictionaryFieldType] DEFAULT (newid()),
[PlanTypeID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[FieldID] [nvarchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[FieldTypeID] [int] NULL,
[ParentFieldIDSectionTitle] [nvarchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
```

`#tblSelectedFields`

```
FieldID nvarchar(255),  
PlanTypeID UniqueIdentifier,  
FieldText nvarchar(MAX),  
sequence int,  
FieldType nvarchar(100),  
IsFinancial bit
```

[UPDATE 3]

Tried the suggestion by @Mack, but a new error emerged. `Expression type uniqueidentifier is invalid for COLLATE clause.` This is caused by the @ClientID having a data type of uniqueidentifier. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us the tables please. I can't see any varchar comparisons

Comment: I am using `#tblPlanTypes` in the main query versus the tables `ClientDataDictionary` and `ClientDataDictionaryFieldType`. Inside the sub query [inside the `AND EXISTS(...)` query], I am using the temp table `#tblSelectedFields`

Comment: "I can't see any varchar comparisons". Should we guess what columns are varchar?

Comment: Is `COLLATE` used for varchars only?

Answer (score 2):

First of all - if you include the descriptions of the tables in your example people here will be able to help you a lot quicker.

Second to debug this query yourself break it into logical parts(separate any subqueries, remove tables one at a time), then remove the where clauses one by from each logical part until your query works, this will help you identify the cause of the problem, remember that the join clauses could also be the problem.

Finally, the code below will allow you to determine the collation type for each column you are querying, it's from [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/16/sql-server-find-collation-of-database-and-table-column-using-t-sql/) by Pinal Dave

```
USE yourdb
GO
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECT_ID IN ( SELECT OBJECT_ID
                     FROM sys.objects
                     WHERE type = 'U'
                     AND name = 'yourtable')
AND name IN('yourcolumn1','yourcolumn2',.....,'yourcolumnX')
```

Thanks for the table definitions...
At first glance, your collate issue lies with this field

> PlanTypeId nvarchar(50)

used in this join: `INNER JOIN #tblPlanTypes pt ON cdd.PlanTypeID = pt.PlanTypeID` 
if you apply the COLLATE to the join you should resolve your problem.

Comment: so it should be `INNER JOIN #tblPlanTypes pt ON cdd.PlanTypeID = pt.PlanTypeID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT?`

Comment: Tried it, but a new error emerged. `Expression type uniqueidentifier is invalid for COLLATE clause.` This is caused by the @ClientID having a data type of uniqueidentifier. Any suggestions

Comment: Right undo that, instead put the collation on your temporary table declaration for #tblPlanTypes: `PlanTypeId nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Answer (score 0):

You need to place COLLATE keywords after textual (char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar) field names in comparison/join operators - 'alias1.txtfield1 COLLATE something = alias2.txtfield2 COLLATE something'. There's no point in using COLLATE with integer fields (I hope your IDs are of integer variety?).

Comment: Actually, `@CleintID` is of `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` data type. I've updated  my query regarding the issue.

Comment: collation doesn't affect UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type.

Comment: @gbn Thanks for that info. So how can I go around with this?

Comment: We need the table definitions as I mentioned an hour ago.

Comment: i've posted my table definitions yesterday. see the updated query.